# What standard is the Currency formatting of NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() based on?

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting

I need to format currency correctly based on locale, but our customer disagrees with the default formatting that Java does based on some locales.

What standard is the formatting based on that Java uses for the NumberFormat returned by `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`, if any, and is this documented anywhere?

Below is some example code that shows how Java formats currency based on Locale.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    displayCurrency(Locale.ENGLISH);
    displayCurrency(Locale.FRENCH);
    displayCurrency(Locale.ITALIAN);
}

static public void displayCurrency( Locale currentLocale) {

    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);

    DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
    symbol.setCurrencySymbol("$");

    DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
    currencyFormatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbol);

    System.out.println(
        currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
}
```

Output:

```
English: $9,876,543.21
Italian: $ 9.876.543,21
French: 9 876 543,21 $
```

Comment: I guess this should help : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html

Comment: Not too helpful I'm afraid. The only standards referenced are ISO 4217 and ISO 3166, which are just about the letter codes for currencies and countries.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want here. You want to customize the formatter according to what your customer wants, right?

Comment: @Leo, well maybe, but the first step is too find out what the Java default behaviour is based on.

Comment: I mean, you're trying to find what format suits the format your customer wants?

Comment: I see. You want to see the default patterns that Java uses internally for each code, right?

Comment: I can do that myself with the code I posted, but it would be nice to find it documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I18n in Java is defined by the UNICODE standard, so you can find the information about how to format currencies at http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/detailed_territory_currency_information.html

In the source code, the same information is stored in the JDK rt.jar and localedata.jar files, in packages sun.util.resources and sun.text.resources (files are called CurrencyNames_xx_XX.class)

Comment: Unfortunately, this resource only has very limited information on currency formatting. For one, it misses the location of the currency symbol (as a prefix or as a postfix)

Comment: Also, the currencynames classes don't really contain much useful info either. For example, this is the source code of CurrencyNames_en_US: `public final class CurrencyNames_en_US extends sun.util.resources.LocaleNamesBundle {
    protected final Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
            { "USD", "$" },
        };
    }
}`

Comment: the position you can get from here -- http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/28/by_type/index.html the information seems to be spread in the http://www.unicode.org/cldr/ site

Comment: since it's not in the language spec neither in a JSR, i18n relies solely on the spec in the UNICODE site, it seems

Answer (score -1):

Probably it takes de default curreyncy from the JVM you are using. there is a file currency.data in the lib folder of the jre

Comment: It can be opened with excel 2016... but you can find more apps for open it. Dont know exactly which